# error C2679 template class

Tags: c++

The error occurs in the default constructor

**Error:**
error C2679: binary '=' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

The Code:

```
#ifndef _SLOT_H
#define _SLOT_H
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <class T>
class slot
{
private:
    string key;
    T data;
public:
    slot();
    slot(string str);
    slot(string str, T tempdata);
    slot(const slot &source);
    string getkey();
    T getdata();
    void setkey(string str);
    void setdata(T tempdata);
};

template<class T>
slot<T>::slot()
{
    key = "";
    data = NULL;
}
```

Comment: How are you instantiating the template?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is probably that you are instantiating the template with a type `T` that doesn't allow an `int` to be assigned to it.

Comment: One even worse outcome would be instantiating the class with `string` being the type. It'll compile, but will throw an exception since strings use empty strings, not 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think I know the solution to this issue. Go ahead and put the main in a header file. Should take care of all pointer issues that you are experiencing

For example

take all of the code within main and put it in a file title "Main.h" link this to the other files via the linux comment mount /dev/bin/boot. This will cause the files to be linked at boot up. If you have any other questions lemme know. Also, after you ave linked up the files you may have to reboot for it to work

Happy Programming!